# GroovyPagesTemplateEngine clear cache

Tags: grails

I am using GroovyPagesTemplateEngine in grails 3.2.8. But I am facing Cache problem while creating the createTemplate.

I am ataching the link along with this for further clarification.
http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/GroovyPagesTemplateEngine-GSP-related-re-design-needed-td3215501.html

Is there any soltuion for this?

```
def t = groovyPagesTemplateEngine.createTemplate(gsp,"sample")
def out = new StringWriter()
t.make(model).writeTo(out)
```

The above code works fine for the first time. But when the gsp value changes the template is created for the initial value of the GSP and not taking the new value. So I need a way to clear the cache and also  groovyPagesTemplateEngine.clearPageCache() is not working .  Using it in the service and getting the attrs(HashMap) value in taglib which always shows the old value and not the new gsp value.

Any Suggestions???

Thanks

Comment: The page you linked is 5 years old (or more, for some posts) and does not really describe anything that's related to grails 3.  Can you update your question to describe the problem that you are facing today?

Comment: Hi Daniel, I have revised my post for further clarification. Thanks....

Comment: That does make a lot more sense to me!  Unfortunately I don't know the answer offhand but I'm optimistic that someone will be able to help now!  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I am using the grails v3.3.5 and was experiencing the same problem. To simply clear the template cache and force the page to be re-compiled just call the following code before the createTemplate():

```
groovyPagesTemplateEngine.clearPageCache();
```

That should solve the problem!